TV villain armed missiles with open source
Help me recognize a tv-series or a movie, AND an open sourced project:
The tv-series (or a movie) had a villain hacking a missile system of some sort. The program code was briefly shown on-screen, with a commented section "MISSILES ARMED" (or something similar).
The funny part is, the original author of that (open sourced) code recognized this programming, and submitted "missiles armed" comment right back into the version control of his code. He even blogged about it.
It's wasn't many years ago, I could easily believe answers like "24" and "wordpress", but then again, they might have gotten more publicity, and I could not find anything from google. They might have been a bit less known tv-series and open source project. I'd say the show was from the US. The specifics are a bit blurry in my memory. Maybe someone can remember the show and/or the code project, maybe even find the article about it to back this story up?

Didn't the programmer/blogger name the movie? It seems a bit odd that he wouldn't.

You might be able to find it at http://moviecode.tumblr.com/.

Ok, thanks to John Sensebe's awesome link http://moviecode.tumblr.com/, I was able to find the TV series: Strike Back, and the project really was WordPress!
I really had a blurry memories of this, as the text was actually "WEAPON LOCKED": http://www.viper007bond.com/2010/06/12/so-apparently-wordpress-can-guide-missiles/
The version control commit is here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/15239

Ah. That's why Google was no help: "WEAPON LOCKED", not "MISSILES ARMED". :-)

Thank you all  for the help and also the really nice editing on both the question and the answer!
